# Can I zip a list of numbers with a list of lists?

Tags: python

I have two python lists:

The first list contains 8 numbers:

```
['4554176', '4554178', '4555289', '4555522', '4555661', '4555693', '4555695', '4556068']
```

The second list is a list of 8 lists:

```
[['dune', 'pro', 'pc', 'case'] ['apple', 'typische', 'kaesereiben', 'muster'] ['orientiert', 'profi', 'mac', 'mac'] ['handel', 'hersteller', 'pc', 'gehaeusen'] ['optik', 'kaesereibe', 'nutzer', 'ueberarbeitete', 'apple'] ['design', 'geklont', 'nennt', 'dune', 'pc'] ['oktober', 'form', 'kickstarter', 'projekts', 'realitaet'] ['annehmen', 'preise', 'genannt', 'signifikant']]
```

I want to zip the numbers of the first list with every element of the corresponding list in the list of lists.

Example:

```
[['4554176':'dune', '4554176':'pro', '4554176':'pc', '4554176':'case'],...
```

The example I provided is a dictionary. I know dictionaries dont support duplicate keys, but I want to show you what I am tyring to do.

Maybe a list of tuples is better?

Comment: this `['4554176':'dune', '4554176':'pro', ...` is invalid syntax. Update the expected result

Comment: You have not clarified whether the result should be a list of lists, or a flat list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given

```
numbers = ['4554176', '4554178', '4555289', '4555522', '4555661', '4555693', '4555695', '4556068']
lists   = [
    ['dune', 'pro', 'pc', 'case'],
    ['apple', 'typische', 'kaesereiben', 'muster'],
    ['orientiert', 'profi', 'mac', 'mac'],
    ['handel', 'hersteller', 'pc', 'gehaeusen'],
    ['optik', 'kaesereibe', 'nutzer', 'ueberarbeitete', 'apple'],
    ['design', 'geklont', 'nennt', 'dune', 'pc'],
    ['oktober', 'form', 'kickstarter', 'projekts', 'realitaet'],
    ['annehmen', 'preise', 'genannt', 'signifikant']
]
```

A list comprehension would work:

```
result = [(n,word) for (n,l) in zip(numbers, lists) for word in l]
```

Output

```
[
  ('4554176', 'dune'),
  ('4554176', 'pro'),
  ('4554176', 'pc'),
  ('4554176', 'case'),
  ('4554178', 'apple'),
  ('4554178', 'typische'),
  ('4554178', 'kaesereiben'),
  ('4554178', 'muster'),
  ('4555289', 'orientiert'),
  ('4555289', 'profi'),
  ('4555289', 'mac'),
  ('4555289', 'mac'),
  ('4555522', 'handel'),
  ('4555522', 'hersteller'),
  ('4555522', 'pc'),
  ('4555522', 'gehaeusen'),
  ('4555661', 'optik'),
  ('4555661', 'kaesereibe'),
  ('4555661', 'nutzer'),
  ('4555661', 'ueberarbeitete'),
  ('4555661', 'apple'),
  ('4555693', 'design'),
  ('4555693', 'geklont'),
  ('4555693', 'nennt'),
  ('4555693', 'dune'),
  ('4555693', 'pc'),
  ('4555695', 'oktober'),
  ('4555695', 'form'),
  ('4555695', 'kickstarter'),
  ('4555695', 'projekts'),
  ('4555695', 'realitaet'),
  ('4556068', 'annehmen'),
  ('4556068', 'preise'),
  ('4556068', 'genannt'),
  ('4556068', 'signifikant'),
]
```

**Edit:** or, if you want the output nested:

```
result = [[(n,word) for word in l] for (n,l) in zip(numbers, lists)]
```

Output:

```
[
  [('4554176', 'dune'), ('4554176', 'pro'), ('4554176', 'pc'), ('4554176', 'case')],
  [('4554178', 'apple'), ('4554178', 'typische'), ('4554178', 'kaesereiben'), ('4554178', 'muster')],
  [('4555289', 'orientiert'), ('4555289', 'profi'), ('4555289', 'mac'), ('4555289', 'mac')],
  [('4555522', 'handel'), ('4555522', 'hersteller'), ('4555522', 'pc'), ('4555522', 'gehaeusen')],
  [('4555661', 'optik'), ('4555661', 'kaesereibe'), ('4555661', 'nutzer'), ('4555661', 'ueberarbeitete'), ('4555661', 'apple')],
  [('4555693', 'design'), ('4555693', 'geklont'), ('4555693', 'nennt'), ('4555693', 'dune'), ('4555693', 'pc')],
  [('4555695', 'oktober'), ('4555695', 'form'), ('4555695', 'kickstarter'), ('4555695', 'projekts'), ('4555695', 'realitaet')],
  [('4556068', 'annehmen'), ('4556068', 'preise'), ('4556068', 'genannt'), ('4556068', 'signifikant')],
]
```

Answer (score 2):

Your expected results seem like you're looking for a list but you're using colons like it were a dict. By the data I assume you need a list of lists of tuples. In that case `zip` and `itertools.repeat` are your friend.

```
list1 = ['4554176', '4554178', '4555289', '4555522', '4555661', '4555693', '4555695', '4556068']
list2 = [['dune', 'pro', 'pc', 'case'], ['apple', 'typische', 'kaesereiben', 'muster'], ['orientiert', 'profi', 'mac', 'mac'], ['handel', 'hersteller', 'pc', 'gehaeusen'], ['optik', 'kaesereibe', 'nutzer', 'ueberarbeitete', 'apple'], ['design', 'geklont', 'nennt', 'dune', 'pc'], ['oktober', 'form', 'kickstarter', 'projekts', 'realitaet'], ['annehmen', 'preise', 'genannt', 'signifikant']]

result = [list(zip(repeat(s), l)) for s, l in zip(list1, list2)]
```

Result:

```
[[('4554176', 'dune'), ('4554176', 'pro'), ('4554176', 'pc'), ('4554176', 'case')], [('4554178', 'apple'), ('4554178', 'typische'), ('4554178', 'kaesereiben'), ('4554178', 'muster')], [('4555289', 'orientiert'), ('4555289', 'profi'), ('4555289','mac'), ('4555289', 'mac')], [('4555522', 'handel'), ('4555522', 'hersteller'), ('4555522', 'pc'), ('4555522', 'gehaeusen')], [('4555661', 'optik'), ('4555661', 'kaesereibe'), ('4555661', 'nutzer'), ('4555661', 'ueberarbeitete'), ('4555661', 'apple')], [('4555693', 'design'), ('4555693', 'geklont'), ('4555693', 'nennt'), ('4555693', 'dune'), ('4555693', 'pc')], [('4555695', 'oktober'), ('4555695', 'form'),('4555695', 'kickstarter'), ('4555695', 'projekts'), ('4555695', 'realitaet')], [('4556068', 'annehmen'), ('4556068', 'preise'), ('4556068', 'genannt'), ('4556068', 'signifikant')]]
```

P.S: `list2` was missing commas between each sub-list I resolved that above.

> Maybe a list of tuples is better?

**IMHO**: You may honestly want to use a `dict` for this data as the above is overkill for the data represented. Also it'd be MUCH more simple to convert.

```
result = dict(zip(list1, list2))
```

Result:

```
{'4554176': ['dune', 'pro', 'pc', 'case'], '4554178': ['apple', 'typische', 'kaesereiben', 'muster'], '4555289': ['orientiert', 'profi', 'mac', 'mac'], '4555522': ['handel', 'hersteller', 'pc', 'gehaeusen'], '4555661': ['optik', 'kaesereibe', 'nutzer', 'ueberarbeitete', 'apple'], '4555693': ['design', 'geklont', 'nennt', 'dune', 'pc'], '4555695': ['oktober', 'form', 'kickstarter', 'projekts', 'realitaet'], '4556068': ['annehmen', 'preise', 'genannt', 'signifikant']}
```

**Although** If you want a list of tuples, then simply use my first approach and wrap it in `itertools.chain`:

```
result = list(chain(*(list(zip(repeat(s), l)) for s, l in zip(list1, list2))))
```

Result:

```
[('4554176', 'dune'), ('4554176', 'pro'), ('4554176', 'pc'), ('4554176', 'case'), ('4554178', 'apple'), ('4554178', 'typische'), ('4554178', 'kaesereiben'), ('4554178', 'muster'), ('4555289', 'orientiert'), ('4555289', 'profi'), ('4555289', 'mac'), ('4555289', 'mac'), ('4555522', 'handel'), ('4555522', 'hersteller'), ('4555522', 'pc'), ('4555522', 'gehaeusen'), ('4555661', 'optik'), ('4555661', 'kaesereibe'), ('4555661', 'nutzer'), ('4555661', 'ueberarbeitete'), ('4555661', 'apple'), ('4555693', 'design'), ('4555693', 'geklont'), ('4555693', 'nennt'), ('4555693', 'dune'), ('4555693', 'pc'), ('4555695', 'oktober'), ('4555695', 'form'), ('4555695', 'kickstarter'), ('4555695', 'projekts'), ('4555695', 'realitaet'), ('4556068', 'annehmen'), ('4556068', 'preise'), ('4556068', 'genannt'), ('4556068', 'signifikant')]
```

**Extra**, here's functional approaches to both ways other than the dict result. (they require `itertools.starmap` FYI)

`list` of `list`s

```
list(map(list, starmap(zip, zip(map(repeat, list1), list2))))
```

`list` of `tuple`s

```
list(chain(*starmap(zip, zip(map(repeat, list1), list2))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Create temp list for every item(with repeatation 4 times) of frist list and then `zip` with first list of 2nd list.

```
[list(zip([l1[i]]*len(l2[i]), l2[i])) for i in range(len(l2))]
```

Answer (score 1):

Python does not support duplicate keys. But maybe you can make them into a key-array dict?

```py
a = ['4554176', '4554178', '4555289', '4555522', '4555661', '4555693', '4555695', '4556068']
b = [['dune', 'pro', 'pc', 'case'], ['apple', 'typische', 'kaesereiben', 'muster'], ['orientiert', 'profi', 'mac', 'mac'], ['handel', 'hersteller', 'pc', 'gehaeusen'], ['optik', 'kaesereibe', 'nutzer', 'ueberarbeitete', 'apple'], ['design', 'geklont', 'nennt', 'dune', 'pc'], ['oktober', 'form', 'kickstarter', 'projekts', 'realitaet'], ['annehmen', 'preise', 'genannt', 'signifikant']]
c = {}

for i in range(len(a)):
    c[a[i]] = b[i]

print(c)
```

Output: `{'4555289': ['orientiert', 'profi', 'mac', 'mac'], '4555693': ['design', 'geklont', 'nennt', 'dune', 'pc'], '4555522': ['handel', 'hersteller', 'pc', 'gehaeusen'], '4556068': ['annehmen', 'preise', 'genannt', 'signifikant'], '4554176': ['dune', 'pro', 'pc', 'case'], '4555695': ['oktober', 'form', 'kickstarter', 'projekts', 'realitaet'], '4555661': ['optik', 'kaesereibe', 'nutzer', 'ueberarbeitete', 'apple'], '4554178': ['apple', 'typische', 'kaesereiben', 'muster']}`

Or, maybe an array of tiny dicts:

```py
a = ['4554176', '4554178', '4555289', '4555522', '4555661', '4555693', '4555695', '4556068']
b = [['dune', 'pro', 'pc', 'case'], ['apple', 'typische', 'kaesereiben', 'muster'], ['orientiert', 'profi', 'mac', 'mac'], ['handel', 'hersteller', 'pc', 'gehaeusen'], ['optik', 'kaesereibe', 'nutzer', 'ueberarbeitete', 'apple'], ['design', 'geklont', 'nennt', 'dune', 'pc'], ['oktober', 'form', 'kickstarter', 'projekts', 'realitaet'], ['annehmen', 'preise', 'genannt', 'signifikant']]
c = []

for i in range(len(a)):
    key = a[i]
    for j in range(len(b[i])):
        c.append({ a[i]: b[i][j] })

print(c)
```

Output: `[{'4554176': 'dune'}, {'4554176': 'pro'}, {'4554176': 'pc'}, {'4554176': 'case'}, {'4554178': 'apple'}, {'4554178': 'typische'}, {'4554178': 'kaesereiben'}, {'4554178': 'muster'}, {'4555289': 'orientiert'}, {'4555289': 'profi'}, {'4555289': 'mac'}, {'4555289': 'mac'}, {'4555522': 'handel'}, {'4555522': 'hersteller'}, {'4555522': 'pc'}, {'4555522': 'gehaeusen'}, {'4555661': 'optik'}, {'4555661': 'kaesereibe'}, {'4555661': 'nutzer'}, {'4555661': 'ueberarbeitete'}, {'4555661': 'apple'}, {'4555693': 'design'}, {'4555693': 'geklont'}, {'4555693': 'nennt'}, {'4555693': 'dune'}, {'4555693': 'pc'}, {'4555695': 'oktober'}, {'4555695': 'form'}, {'4555695': 'kickstarter'}, {'4555695': 'projekts'}, {'4555695': 'realitaet'}, {'4556068': 'annehmen'}, {'4556068': 'preise'}, {'4556068': 'genannt'}, {'4556068': 'signifikant'}]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `product()` in a list comprehension:

```
from itertools import product

lst1 = list('123')
lst2 = [list('ab'), list('cd'), list('ef')]

[list(product(*i)) for i in zip(lst1, lst2)]
# [[('1', 'a'), ('1', 'b')], [('2', 'c'), ('2', 'd')], [('3', 'e'), ('3', 'f')]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I like this combination of [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) with an inner `zip`.

```
import itertools

v1 =['4554176', '4554178', '4555289']
v2 = [
    ['dune', 'pro', 'pc', 'case'],
    ['apple', 'typische', 'kaesereiben', 'muster'],
    ['orientiert', 'profi', 'mac', 'mac'],
]


result = [list(itertools.product([x], y)) for (x, y) in zip(v1, v2)]
print(result)
```

This is similar to @beer44's answer, except that `product` replaces the multiplication by 4